# Enabled and Disabled submit button when multiple fields are empty isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have here script for Enabled and Disabled submit button. I tried to use each function but isn't working. Every fields had it's value from database. The process should not allowed to submit if one of the fields was empty. Every fields has a value because I used it for editing window. Any help will appreciate. Thanks..

And this my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cj6v8/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var saveButton = $("#save");
    var empty = true;
    $('input[type="text"]').change(function () {
        $('.inputs').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() != "") {
                empty = false;
            } else {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (!empty) {
            saveButton.prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
            saveButton.prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
}); // END OF DOCUMENT READY
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to init  `empty` to `false` and cange it only if you find empty inputs inside to loop. http://jsfiddle.net/cj6v8/1/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the first `else` statement.

When `$('.inputs').each(...` iterates through your fields the `empty` variable is re-assigned a new value *for every input field*. In other words, the way you did it, only the last field was significant. (To test it, try this: leave the last one empty, and the button will be disabled, no matter what you put in the first two fields.)

Instead, try initializing `empty` at `false` just before the loop (you assume your fields are all filled with something), and then, when you iterate, as soon as you come across an empty field, set `empty` to `true`.

```
var empty = false;
$('.inputs').each(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "")
        empty = true;
});
```

As you can see, I removed the problematic `else`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to submit when **at least one** field is empty you'll need to do this:

```
....
var empty = true;
$('input[type="text"]').change(function () {
    empty = false;
    $('.inputs').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            empty = true;
            break;
         }
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

each is asynchronous, http://jsfiddle.net/cj6v8/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var saveButton = $("#save");

    $('input[type="text"]').change(function() {
        var empty = true;
        var inputs = $('.inputs');
        inputs.each(function(i) {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                console.log($(this).val());
                empty = false;
            }
            if (i === inputs.length-1) saveButton.attr("disabled", !empty);
        });
    });
});// END OF DOCUMENT READY
```